# Deploying NX Monorepo with React / Express to Vercel

Tags: reactjs, express, vercel, monorepo, nx-monorepo

https://github.com/clearhost-cmd/helloapp

I am struggling to deploy my NX Monorepo to Vercel.

The NX Monorepo works fine on localhost - no issues.

However, I cannot get it to work on Vercel.

There's no errors, it just doesn't deploy at all properly resulting in 404.

Deployment:

[image]

Config:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot deploy the entire NX Monorepo to a single Vercel project. You would have to create separate projects for each of your NX Monorepo apps and utilize Multi Zone Rewrite and basePath to route your route to the Vercel project server URL. Each project app should include the vercel.json file with the Rewrite configuration.

Multi Zone Rewrite and basePath
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/multi-zones
https://vercel.com/guides/how-can-i-serve-multiple-projects-under-a-single-domain#with-next.js-multi-zones

Nx deploy guide to Vercel
https://nx.dev/recipes/react/deploy-nextjs-to-vercel

Example:

NX Monorepo apps:

- admin: default path: /admin
- frontend: default path: /

```
// vercel.json

{
  "rewrites": [
    { "source": "/admin", "destination": "https://your-admin-project.com/" },
    { "source": "/admin/:match*", "destination": "https://your-admin-project.vercel.com/:match*" },
    { "source": "/", "destination": "https://your-frontend-project.vercel.com/" },
    { "source": "/:match*", "destination": "https://your-frontend-project.vercel.com/:match*" }
  ]
}
```

Rewrites are processed from first to last and the first matching rewrite rule will be used. This means that the /admin/:match* rule must come before the /:match* rule.

Here's an example of the build setup.
[image]